# What exactly is Identity server and what is the purpose of using it

Tags: linux, security, ldap, user-management, identity-management

Currently I am working on a single sign on middleware application and I am confused with identity server and LDAP.
I got to know LDAP is used for identity provisioning means it contains user records but I am not able to understand the purpose of identity servers.

I have searched on google but I am able to see different identity server products but I am not able to find what exactly isa identity server.

Can anybody any resource or can anybody explain.

Thanks,
Nikhil Agrawal

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: an identity server is a system or set of technologies that can be used for identity management. Capabilities generally expected of [such a system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management_system) include:

> - Access governance system
> - Identity and access management system
> - Entitlement management system
> - User provisioning system

A good starting point to understanding it is the [Wikipedia article on Identity Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management).

This defines Identity Management as:

> Identity management (IdM) is the task of controlling information about users on computers.

An identity server is more correctly referred to as a [Identity Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management_system).

Under this heading (and as listed in the [Solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management_system#Solutions)), LDAP is a Directory Service (i.e. a repository of identity information).

Identity Management Services are typically expected to be more than that, notably providing something along the lines of RBAC - i.e. not just identity, by access/authorisation, and delegation.

That being said - and as noted in the article on [Identity Management Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management_system#Electronic_identity_management):

> In general, electronic IdM can be said to cover the management of any form of digital identities.

Which I suspect is the basic answer you need - although it is worth noting that

> identity management itself falls under the umbrella of IT security

While I am not sure that last element is of particular relevance to you, it is worth noting that such systems are always almost security sensitive.

So, an identity management system - i.e. an identity server (which may be part, or the totality, of the IdM - is a system matching the following description:

> one can consider identity management as the management of information (as held in a directory) that represents items identified in real life (e.g. users, organizations, devices, services, etc

In relation to LDAP - LDAP can be configured as an Identity Management System, or to be the backing repository of a broader IdM system (for example, LDAP can provide the information to SAML or Shibboleth).

So LDAP is just a specific implementation of an IdM system:

> The design of such systems requires explicit information and identity engineering tasks

It is also an implementation of one of the original IdM approaches, [X.500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.500).